# PHP Session Script Semi-Functional

Tags: php, session, timeout

I posted a question here yesterday and got a quick response. Great community!

I hope someone can help enlighten me (a newbie to PHP) about my script below and why its execution is inconsistent.

I'm using the following session.php file to check for login and session timeout:

`

```
function logged_in() {
    return isset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    session_write_close();
}

function session_expired() {
    $now = time();
    $limit = $now - 7200; // 2 hour
    return isset($_SESSION['last_activity']) && ($_SESSION['last_activity'] < $limit);
    session_write_close();
}

function confirm_logged_in() {
    $now = time();
    if (session_expired()) {
        $_SESSION = array();
        if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
        }
        session_destroy();
        redirect_to("http://domain.com/login.php?logout=2");
        exit;
    }
    elseif (!logged_in()) {
        redirect_to("http://domain.com/login.php");
        exit;
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['last_activity'] = $now;
        session_write_close();
    }
}
```

?>`

At the top of each page I then have:

`<?php require_once("../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?> defines some other functions I use
<?php confirm_logged_in(); ?>`

What's happening is that the session_expired() doesn't always get triggered and instead of  redirect_to("http://domain.com/login.php?logout=2"); it goes to redirect_to("http://domain.com/login.php");

Can anyone see what may be wrong?

Comment: You have `session_write_close()` after your `return` statement. That line won't be executed.

Comment: I see. I have it twice in the two functions logged_in() and session_expired(). I added this based on some research when trying to figure out why my pages were sometimes not loading on the first attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a couple of different places, you have `session_write_close()` after a `return`. A `return` statement is always the last thing executed in the function.

Also, just to make sure, you are calling `session_start()` to actually start a session, right?

Comment: I had to double check (that's how new I am to this, haha!) but yes. I forgot to add it to the top. it starts with session_start(); before function logged_in(). I will delete the session_write_close() from those two lines and try that out. You guys are super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

So, I took the advice of the nice people who recommended I remove the session_write_close() from sections of the code. Great advice!

However, that didn't solve my problem. My pages were still not loading when moving around the site and this was happening only sporadically.

Turns out I needed to set $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); in my login page. That solved the problem. Now my pages load consistently and quickly. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Hey Mike, remember they only adviced you to remove that line of code just because it was being called after return so it was never being executed, php by defaults executes session_write_close() after a php script finish loading but if you are redirecting you should always use session_write_close() before redirect.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I have actually started having problems with my password protected forum being spammed by spambots. I wonder if my sessions are being highjacked or something because I was missing the session_write_close() command? I have no idea how to stop them. I will post another question including my login script to see if anyone can point out security holes.

Comment: Try to add a captcha to effectively avoid robots spamming your site.